# Datepicker with Twitter boostrap shows up but doesn't change date

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to use [datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) with twitter bootstrap with the following code but while the date-picker calendar shows up, it doesn't change the date in the form when I click on it.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="dp1">Meeting Date</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append date" id="dp1" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
            <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" readonly>
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm calling datepicker with these lines :

```
<link href="css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#dp1').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Am I missing something ? There's a call to jQuery but if I remove it, the calendar doesn't show up anymore.

Comment: hey debug the code using firebug for Firefox and console in Chrome as this code looks fine.Check what error you are getting when you select date if get.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you select a `div` as a date-picker thats why it wont work 
you have to select textbox as a datepicker

like

```
$('#dp1>input').datepicker();
```